# How do we handle a browser pop-up using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am currently using Selenium Webdriver and have started with automation but as soon as i open the browser it gives a popup wherein in need to enter the username and password but i cannot inspect those fields at all.Kindly help how to solve this issue? Somebosy suggested me the below code but it isnt working:
driver.get("http://un:pwd@url");

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not just *some* browser pop-up but a BasicAuth dialog. A way to handle it with Firefox WebDriver is to use the AutoAuth plugin. Set it up as described on the [download page](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/autoauth/) and use that Firefox profile for your Selenium WebDriver tests as described in this [tutorial](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/05/how-to-create-and-use-custom-firefox.html).

Answer (score 0):

Many people use AutoIt to automate entering username and passwords without relying on browser plugins: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

You can also try passing the credentials inline on the address bar (really not a good idea as it blatantly exposes credentials in the code and during test runs), but if you're really stuck you can try this:

http://username:password@example.com/

This uses the HTTP Authorization field.

Comment: Could you let me know the link to install autoit in mac?...i tried yest and installed some virus...

Comment: It is not available for Mac, only Windows.